# How to do significance testing on averages of regression coefficients across multiple groups?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, t-test, levenes-test

I have over 1000 respondents each with their own regression coefficients. I am analyzing data by different segments by averaging the constant and coefficient scores for each group.  Sometimes I will have 2 groups (gender, yes/no questions, etc.) and sometimes I will have multiple groups (Ethnicity, age groups, etc.) What significance test should be used to see if the average coefficient scores are significantly different from each other?

Answer (score 1):

What sort of model are you fitting?  It sounds to me like you want to fit the regression coefficients as random effects.

If that is the case, I'd recommend REML (REstricted Maximum Likelihood) estimation and an F-test (which will probably be an approximate F test, but since there are no Normal distributions outside computers, they are all approximate anyway.)

In the event that your computer and software are incapable of fitting mixed models, you could also do a weighted analysis of variance of the regression coefficients classified by your groups.  The weights should be proportional to the inverse of the standard errors of the regression coefficients.

With all that said, remember that main effects models can be deceiving when there are non-additive effects among the classification variables.

Comment: Each respondent went through a conjoint study and regression models were run on each respondent.  The way I am running the segments is by averaging the coefficients of the people within each group.  I would be using SPSS for the analysis.

Comment: I thought it was something like this.  I'd fit a mixed model with random slopes and intercepts.  I'm pretty sure SPSS fits mixed models with the Advanced Statistics module.

Comment: [Hausman test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausman_test) might be useful here